# Excel - List unique values in table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can't figure out but I need to filter a range in excel (like A1:G5 ) to a list as a column of unique values.

**Unique** formula returns a table not a list

eg.

```
A  B  C

A  C  D

B  D  A
```

Should Return

```
A

B

C

D
```

Any clue ?

Comment: Use`TOCOL()` with `UNIQUE()`. In your case `=UNIQUE(TOCOL(A1:G5))`

Comment: `=UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,A1:C3),";"),TRUE)`

Comment: @JvdV =UNIQUE(TOCOL(A1:G5)) works like a charm. Thx

Answer (score 3):

Thx @JvdV

```
=UNIQUE(TOCOL(A1:G5))
```

Works great !